# Getting a fresh web browser page from a python script

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to use a python web script to display some html, pause for a second and then post form data to another python script that will display some different html.

script1.py:

```
print "Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<body>"
print "<p>Some temporary info"
print "</body>"
print "</html>"

time.sleep(1)

params = urllib.urlencode({'test': "test_info"})
response = urllib.urlopen("http://www.exampleurl.com/cgi-bin/script2.py", params)
print response.read()
```

When I run this the browser window shows both the html from script1 "Some temporary info" and the html from script2 (i.e. the temporary info is not temporary). How can I get the browser to start a fresh page with the script2 html only, as if I had clicked submit on a true form rather than faking it with urllib?

EDIT: As suggested by Hackman, I have tried using client side redirect, such as:

```
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;URL=http://www.exampleurl.com/cgi-bin/script2.py\">"
```

This does provide a fresh browser page for script2.py, but I cannot see how to provide the POST data with this method.

Answer (score 0):

You are ending the html and then trying to add to it.

Just try and see what happens if you take two html files on to each other, it is invalid.

You might want to have the client request the page itself.

You might want to create a client side redirect :
http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html

Comment: Client side redirect does provide a fresh browser page, but from what I have seen it doesn't allow using POST data in the redirect.

Comment: Basically you want to create a proxy, so you redirect to a new page on your server that fetches the third party page and displays it.

Comment: It's unclear to me from what you have said how I can get the POST data, that is dynamically generated in script1.py, to the proxy page that calls script2.py.

Comment: generate a form data, a cookie or some url encoded in the query string to call the second site. http://easyway2pro.blogspot.com/2012/11/ways-to-pass-data-between-web-pages.html